# MainWindow.xaml opens automatically in debugger

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

When I'm running my program from the VS 2015 debugger, I click a button from the main window of my program which opens another window.  When I close that window, the program focus returns to MainWindow.xaml.  The debugger then automatically opens the code file for MainWindow.xaml in a Preview Tab.  This is quite annoying.  I almost never need to look at this file, but it's always open in my debugger.  Even when I turn off Preview mode, the file opens up in a normal tab.  I can't make this file NOT open while I'm testing my program.

Is this a bug?  Is it a feature I can turn off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools => Options => Debugging => General => Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML =>
Preview selected elements in Live Visual Tree